# I'm unable to call a Fragment within onTabSelected of another Fragment that implements ActionTab Listener

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-viewpager

I am trying to create a Fragment that has a ListView in the content section, as a default view. There are ActionBar tabs to this view. I'm able to create that so far.

The LaunchListFragment Code

```
public class LaunchListFragment extends ListFragment implements ActionBar.TabListener {
public static  String LIST_TYPE = "invalid";
GenericListData g_data[] = null;
   private ViewPager mViewPager;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View result = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_launch_list,
            container, false);

    setActionTabs();
    setList();
    return (result);
}

public static LaunchListFragment newInstance(String type) {
    LaunchListFragment frag = new LaunchListFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    LIST_TYPE=type;

    args.putString(LIST_TYPE, type);
    frag.setArguments(args);

    return (frag);
}
```

What I wanted is, when you click the onTabSelected(), would like to change the views and I am using PagerFragment with views generated using an FragmentPagerAdapter

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {

       getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
       .add(android.R.id.content,
            new PagerFragment()).commit();
}
```

The trouble is, I can't use getChildFragmentManager or getFragmentManager to call the PagerFragment, I get compilation errors to change the PagerFragment to app.Fragment. Even if I change that, it still complaints.

I suspect there is some sort of clash between support.Fragment and app.Fragment.

Is there a different way of approach to acheive this other than using nested Fragments?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Enter your error, when you get?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to use the viewPager, have your two fragments to show on tab selections(on action bar). Use FragmentStatePagerAdapter or FragmentPagerAdapter depending on the need, then initialise the viewPager and set the adapter. Then in 'onTabSelected()' get tab postion then show the corresponding viewPager's page.

```
       FragmentPagerAdapter fragmentStagePageAdapter = new SearchStatePagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.venues_tabhost_layout, container, false);

    mViewPager = ( com.edenpod.goinout.view.ViewPager) mView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.removeAllViews();
    mViewPager.setAdapter(fragmentStagePageAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
    ----------------
    ---------------
   --------------
    }

    public void onTabChanged(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
    int pos = tab.getCurrentTab();
    if( mViewPager!= null && pos == 0 ) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(pos);
    } else if( mViewPager != null && pos == 1 ) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(pos);
    } else if( mViewPager != null && pos == 2 ) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(pos);
    }
    }

// Example PagerAdapter
public class SearchStatePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

private ArrayList<Fragment> mFragmentsList;

public SearchStatePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    mFragmentsList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    mFragmentsList.add(new VenueSearchFragment());
    mFragmentsList.add(new PeopleSearchFragment());
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragmentsList.size();
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = mFragmentsList.get(position);
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = mFragmentsList.get(position);
            break;
    }
    return fragment;
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Although your solution seems to be a working one - ie getting Fragments displayed on onTabSelect(), this might not be the best way in my case. I have a MainActivity that has two fragments (for tablet view) and a DetailActivity that launches a single fragment for Phone. The reason I wanted the fragment to have tabs, so that pager will be inside the fragment. This would avoid having to duplicate setting ActionBar tabs in MainActivity and DetailActivity. This Edit mode is not allowing me to type my comment in paragraphs, so this comment may be confusing.